Typescript type narrowing inside if does not work
I have an issue with type narrowing and I can't get it to work.
The type of event.data is { id: string; } | { progress: number; } and not { id: string; }
Any idea what's wrong?
Typescript Playground
const events = ['event1', 'event2'] as const

type EventName = (typeof events)[number]

type EventData = {
  event1: {
    id: string
  }
  event2: {
    progress: number
  }
}

type DemoEvent<T extends EventName> = {
  name: T
  data: EventData[T]
}

const createEvent = <TName extends EventName>(name: TName, data: string): DemoEvent<TName> => {
  return {
    name,
    data: JSON.parse(data) as EventData[TName],
  }
}

const isEventName = (name: string): name is EventName => {
  return events.includes(name as EventName)
}

const onMessage = (name: string, data: string) => {
  if (!isEventName(name)) {
    return
  }

  const event = createEvent(name, data)
  if (event.name === 'event1') {
    console.log(event.data)
  }
}


Is the playground link broken or? because it contains ⋛ and not correct.

I don't really know why this works but it works.. https://tsplay.dev/wE0j3W

This isn't a [mre] because you're doing JSON parsing. I could call onMessage("event1", "OOPSIEDOODLE") and there'd be no error. Could you please [edit] to deal only with objects and then try to show the same issue?  The underlying problem here is probably that TName can be a union and thus data could be the union of data types, messing up the intended correlation, but since data can literally be any old garbage string, it's hard to even begin to discuss it.  (Prev comment "works" because modified createEvent distributes over unions)

@kennarddh The reason that works is that it changes the return type of createEvent from DemoEvent<'event1' | 'event2'> (which can't be narrowed) to DemoEvent<'event1'> | DemoEvent<'event2'> (which can).

@kennarddh Wow, thanks. This works indeed. And thanks Chris for explaining it.
